# How can I make fotorama SEO-friendly. How to make Alt attribute work in fotorama

Tags: jquery, html, fotorama

I have code like this: (I use thumbnail-navigation)

```
<div data-auto="false" data-fit="scaledown" class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-allowfullscreen="true">
         <a href="/IMGNews/Big/example1.jpg" data-caption="image-text1">
<img alt="attribute disappears" src="/IMGNews/Small/example1.jpg">
</a>
 <a href="/IMGNews/Big/example2.jpg" data-caption="image-text2">
<img alt="attribute disappears" src="/IMGNews/Small/example2.jpg">
</a>
 <a href="/IMGNews/Big/example3.jpg" data-caption="image-text3">
<img alt="attribute disappears" src="/IMGNews/Small/example3.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

I wanna have the alt-attribute of the img-element.
I have tested to surround the img-element with a div but it doesn't work. If I surround the a-element with a div, then I can see the alt-attribute in the source-code, but the navigation-images disappears and it looks strange.

Comment: Look here. Everything seems to be fixed already. Or at least there is solution.
https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/329